# Identify 5 pin ic SOT23-5 with "SA10" marking

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

I am disassembling an 100A Mauch Power sensor and I have managed to identify every component except a 5 pin IC with "SA10" printed on the top.

Can anyone identify this component?

[image].

Comment: Without any more info it looks like an op amp for offset adjustment. Likely the MCP601.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely an MCP601. On a board that's made by the same manufacturer they state it has an MCP601

> The electronic on the board is powered by an independent 4.0V LDO
> (LP2985-4.0) and the offset shifting is realized by an OP from
> Microchip (MCP601) specially designed for microprocessors analog
> inputs.
> Source: https://www.mauch-electronic.com/hs-sensor-product

Also the datasheet for the MCP601 says this:
[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/MCP601T-I-OT/418617